# in pine-script how prevent consecutive alert in multiful condition?

Tags: pine-script

hi im pine script newbie :)
i made some script for a days refer to stackoverflow and it almost done but there is something ploblem in code, that is consecutive alert.

i made 4 alerts(buy25,50,75,99) for diversified investment and my intention is once met one condition  shutdown other conditions,  so one conditon enter by one bar (ex: if buy25 --> ignore buy50,75,99)

here is my full code

```
//@version=4
study(title="test1", overlay=true)

//noise ratio
R = 0.5
range = high[1] - low[1]

//SMA Split
longa= close >= sma(close, 3)
longb= close >= sma(close, 5)
longc= close >= sma(close, 10)
longd= close >= sma(close, 20)

sm3 = if (longa)
    1
else
    0
sm5 = if (longb)
    1
else
    0
sm10 = if (longc)
    1
else
    0
sm20 = if (longd)
    1
else
    0

smq = sm3 + sm5 + sm10 + sm20

//show target price
buy_price = open + R * range
plot(buy_price, title='buy_price', color= color.black, linewidth = 2, style=plot.style_stepline)
BUYING = high > buy_price  and smq>=1
plotshape(BUYING, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar ,color=color.purple, size=size.small)
exit = high[1] > buy_price[1] and smq[1] >= 1 and time_close
plotshape(exit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar , size=size.small)


// buying condition
buy25 = smq == 1 and close > buy_price
buy50 = smq == 2 and close > buy_price
buy75 = smq == 3 and close > buy_price
buy99 = smq == 4 and close > buy_price
CLOSE = time_close

//for prevent duplicate alert
var bought = false
buy_25 = false
buy_50 = false
buy_75 = false
buy_99 = false
closing = false

if buy25 and not bought
    bought := true
    buy_25 := true

if buy50 and not bought
    bought := true
    buy_50 := true

if buy75 and not bought
    bought := true
    buy_75 := true

if buy99 and not bought
    bought := true
    buy_99 := true

if CLOSE and bought
    bought := false
    closing := true

//alert
alertcondition(closing, title='CLOSE', message='CLOSE')
alertcondition(buy_25, title= 'buy25', message= 'buy25')
alertcondition(buy_50, title= 'buy50', message= 'buy50')
alertcondition(buy_75, title= 'buy75', message= 'buy75')
alertcondition(buy_99, title= 'buy99', message= 'buy99')
```

i was struggle for a days to solve this ploblem( googling, rummage stackoverflow)
and i found using "var bought" but fail to solve..
so anyone have solution to my ploblem , let me know plese!! thank you, have nice day

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing `bought := true` with `bought = true` ?

Comment: error message showing "shadowing variable "bought" which exists in parent scope"